# Check if pickadate.js datepicker has selected today not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, pickadate

I am trying to check if a see if this date picker (pickadate.js) has selected the current day on set. Here is my code:

```js
var today = new Date();

var tomorrow = new Date();

tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);

var nextyear = new Date();

nextyear.setFullYear(nextyear.getFullYear() + 1);

var pickupdatepicker = $("#car-rental-pickup-date").pickadate({
 editable: true,
    format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
    min: today,
    max: nextyear,
    today: "",
    close: "",
    clear: "",
    onSet: function(context) {
    
        var d = new Date(context.select);

        dnotime = new Date(d.toDateString());
        todaynotime =  new Date(today.toDateString());

        var currenthour = new Date().getHours();
        var hourp3 = currenthour + 13;

        console.log (dnotime);
        console.log (todaynotime);

        if (dnotime == todaynotime) {

            time.set({
                disable: [
                { from: [0,0], to: [hourp3,00] }
                ]
            });

            console.log ("today!");

        }else{

            console.log ("not today!");

        }
        
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/themes/default.date.css" id="theme_date">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/picker.js"></script>
<script src="https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/picker.date.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="car-rental-pickup-date" id="car-rental-pickup-date" class="form-control tleft readonly" value="" placeholder="Select Pickup Date" required>
```

But the if statement comparing the two dates isn't working but the console says they are identical. What gives? Can someone check this out and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can't compare date objects unless you convert them to milliseconds first. `d.getTime()` & `today.getTime()`  `if(d==today){//...}`  But you could compare each part of the date to the other, like if(today.getDate()==d.getDate() && today.getMonth()==d.getMonth() && today.getFullYear()==d.getFullYear()){//...}

Comment: Clarification of above - `var dTime = d.getTime()` and `var todayTime = today.getTime()` And then `if(dTime==todayTime){/...}`

Comment: `dnotime = new Date(d.toDateString());` is awful, just do `d.setHours(0,0,0,0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
if (dnotime == todaynotime) {
```

compares two Date objects, so it's always false. Coerce to number first:

```
if (+dnotime == +todaynotime) {
```

However, you can make it simpler than that as `context.select` returns a time value for the local start of the selected date, so you can do:

```
if (context.select == new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))
```

and simplify the preceding code. Here's the original code modified to work:

```js
var today = new Date();
// Set to start of day
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
// Copy today as root for tomorrow
var tomorrow = new Date(today);
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
// And for next year
var nextyear = new Date(today);
nextyear.setFullYear(nextyear.getFullYear() + 1);

var pickupdatepicker = $("#car-rental-pickup-date").pickadate({
 editable: true,
    format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
    min: today,
    max: nextyear,
    today: "",
    close: "",
    clear: "",
    onSet: function(context) {
    
        // Could keep value as number, but OK as Date too
        var d = new Date(context.select);

        // This is unnecessary
        // dnotime = new Date(d.toDateString());
        // todaynotime =  new Date(today.toDateString());

        // Not relevant to issue
        // var currenthour = new Date().getHours();
        // var hourp3 = currenthour + 13;

        // Compare time values
        // Could also do: if (+d == + today) {...}
        if (d.getTime() == today.getTime()) {
        /* Not relevant
            time.set({
                disable: [
                { from: [0,0], to: [hourp3,00] }
                ]
            });
        */
            console.log ("today!");

        } else {
            console.log ("not today!");
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/themes/default.date.css" id="theme_date">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/picker.js"></script>
<script src="https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/picker.date.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="car-rental-pickup-date" id="car-rental-pickup-date" class="form-control tleft readonly" value="" placeholder="Select Pickup Date" required>
```

Comment: I'm not really understanding how to implement the context.select - can you give me a more detailed example? Thanks!